# Cannot fetch GPG public keys with Kleopatra in Windows

Tags: gnupg, gpg4win, kleopatra

Edit: I resolved the problem myself. Please see my answer below.

In Kleopatra (Windows), I have the following key server
[image: Kleopatra Key Server]

When I try to fetch the GPG public key of XUbuntu (`843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092`) using `Lookup on Server` functionality, Kleopatra doesn't return anything.
[image]

I've tried the following servers but nothing changed.

1. hkp://keys.gnupg.net
2. keys.gnupg.net
3. http://gpg-keyserver.de

My Kleopatra version

[image: Kleopatra version]

[image]

How should I debug this problem? Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I haven't solved it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't upgrade GnuPG to the newest version as the web page instructed, and that's why my problem occurred. After updating, I can fetch GPG keys successfully.
[image: Download Gpg4win]

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to fetch the GPG public key of XUbuntu (`843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092`) using Lookup on Server functionality, Kleopatra doesn't return anything

When searching for a hexadecimal key ID or fingerprint (instead of a user ID) you must prefix the string with `0x`.

Changing the search string to `0x843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092` should work.

Comment: I tried that too, but it doesn't work. Evidence: https://imgur.com/a/lr04PSk